# Chrome Extensions: Interacting with page content (injecting content scripts)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I recently created a Google Chrome extension that reads the current website's DOM and makes changes to that DOM, using JavaScript.

**The Goal**

I have a file called `popup.js`, as well as the typical `manifest.json` and `popup.html` files (plus a few others not relevant to the question).

`popup.js` contains the JavaScript code for the extension itself, as well as the code that is supposed to be run within (be injected into) the current page/tab.

The code that should run on the current page needs to access various data from `popup.js`. For example, two checkboxes. Depending on which one is checked, the injected script should act differently.

**What I Know**

- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) can interact with the DOM of a page
- Via [executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi), it seems we can either run a piece of code in string format, or run a separate file

**My Questions**

1. Is there any way to inject a function from `popup.js` into the current page's DOM? Something like `chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: 'myLocalFunction()'})`?
2. Are they forcing developers to input the code as `string` / a separate file, just to enforce the concept they call `isolated worlds` [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment)?
3. If I wanted to build the above-described extension, which has some variables that the injected script should read, how would I do it? Is there any way to pass the variables into the injected function?

   - I have seen [this section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication), but I was not sure if it applied to communication between the extension code and the injected code.

Comment: 1. only as a string 2. the page renderer processes are separate so only serializable data can be transferred 3. messaging (ports or chrome.tabs.sendMessage) or via executeScript with JSON.stringify or chrome.storage

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you. Would you be able to share the simplest solution for passing these three variables: A string from an input field and two checkboxes? That's all I need to send. Should I somehow convert the two boolean values of the checkboxes to string, and send them over with executeScript? It is ~100 lines of code for the entire injected script itself, so would it make sense to write it all as a string?

Comment: There should be lots of examples since this is a really basic action.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, I will try to look again. Just so I have the overall picture, if I go down the route of stringifying my two variables, I would have to put the entire injected code as one big string (except for those three variables)? The best solution is sendMessage?

Comment: The first executeScript passes and sets stringified variables, then in its callback you can run another executeScript with a file or code.

Comment: Hmmm, but the issue is that the script I have needs to make changes to the actual page DOM. So if I run it in the context of the extension (`popup.js`), i.e. as a callback, then it can't do any of that right? It needs to be fully embedded/injected in the page to make changes, no?

Comment: Why? No it's not an issue. The callback runs in the popup (in the extension context) where it can run chrome.tabs.executeScript which will run a second content script in the specified tab's isolated world of content scripts which already has the variables set by the first executeScript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169102/discussion-between-magnus-and-woxxom).